Scroll of Antiochus vs. Books of Maccabees
According to Wikipedia, Megillas Antiochus (the Scroll of Antiochus) is unrelated to the Books of Maccabees except for the fact that it cites some quotations which are contained in 1 and 2 Maccabees, and it also describes the same events which are described in 1 and 2 Maccabees. What are the reasons for such a conclusion about the relation between Megilas Antiochus and the 1st and 2nd Books of Maccabees?

What does "unrelated" mean?

@DoubleAA I do not know, trying to understand.

They are two distinct books that happen to cover the same topic.

If you follow the footnote at the end of Wikipedia's statement, you'll reach the JVL's entry on the Scroll of Antiochus, which features a pretty standard description of the text and its development. The entry describes the mainstream view on the creation of the text.1
One can gather from the JVL's entry that the Books of Maccabees and the Scroll of Antiochus are unrelated for the following reasons:

Language: 1-2 Maccabees as we have them are written in Greek, while the scroll in Aramaic. Many believe that 1 Maccabees was originally written in Hebrew (but 2 Maccabees was indeed originally written in Greek). Either way, the three books do not share the same base language.
Dating: 1-2 Maccabees, as indicated both by the books themselves and by later authors who cited them (e.g. Josephus), as well as modern studies of the works, are believed to have been authored by people who lived in the time of the Maccabees/Chashmonaim, while the scroll, as indicated both by its mention of the destruction of the Mikdash and its usage of Western Middle Aramaic, as well as various traditions regarding its origins, is believed to have been authored by a person who lived ca. the 2nd-5th centuries CE (centuries after the time of the Chashmonaim).
Familiarity with historical circumstances: Both books of Maccabees describe in detail various historic events that led to the Maccabean Revolt and the Jewish war against the Seleucids. The scroll, on the other hand, makes a small mention of Antiochus's megalomaniacal fantasies of conquering the whole world and quickly moves on to describing the defilement of the Mikdash and the killing of the Seleucid general Nicanor. According to the JVL, this indicates the author's ignorance of the real events that led to the revolt.
Nicanor: Both Maccabees and the scroll describe the killing of the Seleucid general Nicanor. But according to the JVL, the scroll's description followed the spirit of how the event was remembered by later generations, as the event that brought on the celebration of Yom Nicanor (13th of Adar; the Fast of Esther is a Geonic custom). 1-2 Maccabees, on the other hand, describe it from the POV of contemporaries or near-contemporaries, before the day became a longstanding traditional celebration.
The Miracle of the Oil: 1-2 Maccabees do not mention the miracle of the oil at all, while the scroll follows the known talmudic tradition that states that Chanukah was/is celebrated for 8 days because of that miracle.

In short, though all three texts describe the same events, they were authored by different individuals, who lived in different periods, had different backgrounds and held different points of view and different interests. For these reasons, they should be considered unrelated.

1 For other views, see here and other sources cited there.
